# Passing variable by reference to web service function?

Tags: c#, rest

Can I pass variable by reference in order to return value to caller. For example, can I use `returnAmount` in case below? I haven't seen such expression in samples I have analysed. What problems I will be faced while using it?

I understand that fact, that I can use custom class with required cont of fields in function return when I need to return more than one variable, but anyway I'm interested in fact is it possible to use `out` like in sample below.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult balance( int amount, out int returnAmount )
  {
  returnAmount = 50;
  return Proceed(a.Balance( amount));
  }
}
```

Comment: is this a web api or .net core controller?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.  Instead create a ViewModel with that as a property.  Update the viewmodel with whatever data you want.  Then return the view and bind everything on the view through razor.  If you don't want the page to completely reload, you'll have to use AJAX or a partial.

```
return View("viewname", viewmodel);
```